# Include content on module install of a custom block

Tags: blocks, 8

I'm using Features for creating a custom module that installs and places blocks on my site, but Features doesn't export content and in this case the block contents will be needed.

I'm trying figure out how to include custom block's content somewhere in my module to my custom blocks appear with some content (to allow editing in 'custom library page') or somehow populate my custom blocks after module install with a automate tool.

PS: From now, I've putting content after module install using mysqldump (export site A, insert site B), but its not safe procedure.

Any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use https://drupal.org/project/default_content for install time content. For ongoing content, there is Entity Pilot (disclaimer: my product) https://drupal.org/project/entity_pilot.